# how to make url string absolute?

Tags: 8, uri

In order to get entity link, I'm using:

```
$entity->getTranslation($language)->url();
```

So it gives me : /en/node/21

But I want this url to be absolute.

How to pass `$options = array('absolute' => TRUE);` in above node url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The options are the second parameter in `url()`, then you also have to pass the first parameter, which is by default 'canonical':

```
$entity->getTranslation($language)->url('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE]);
```

`url()` is deprecated, so better use `toUrl()`:

```
$entity->getTranslation($language)->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
```

Comment: You can also use `->setAbsolute()` which I find more intuitive than figuring out what options can go in the array. so you will end up with `$entity->getTranslation($language)->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])->setAbsolute()->toString();`

Comment: $entity->getTranslation($language)->toUrl('canonical')->setAbsolute()->toString();

You don't need the absolute option in the toUrl() if using ->setAbsolute()

Comment: $entity->getTranslation($language)->toUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString() If you use setAbsolute(), you don't need to pass 'canonical' either.